# Sorting Numpy arrays using multiple keys

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have an array taken from three different lists:

```
a = [date_DB,singolaData,Pesi]
a=numpy.array(a)
```

The three of them are 2600x1 long, so the final numpy array will be a 2600x3 element.
I am trying to sort the numpy array starting from singoladata (so a[1]) and then for date_DB (so a[0]).
I have sorted the array only for singolaData using this code:

```
b = a [:,a.argsort()]
```

However, my intent would be the one I already specified above. I tried using the numpy lexsort function and I wrote this:

```
        primo=a[0]
        secondo=a[1]
        ind=np.lexsort((secondo,primo))
```

Other than I have to sort my array given the result indices of the lexsort function, the python gives me this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there anyone who has any idea of how to order the array in the best way?

The reason why I need the double sorting, is because the singolaData column has some identical data inside and I need to put a strict order to the series.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think you are mistaking `a[1]` (the second row, with 3 entries) with `a[:,1]` (the second column, corresponding to the 2600 singolaData entries).  Try changing your lexsort approach to `primo=a[:,0]; secondo=a[:,1]`

Comment: I tried this way, but the result is just an array of ordered number from 0 to 2599. Seems like something is not working well.